# Why does the char type not feature on Java's "widening path"?

Tags: java, type-conversion

I understand that Java's automatic type conversion can be summarised by something called a "widening path", and it looks like this:

byte -> short -> int -> long -> float -> double

The following code compiles OK, and illustrates some char/int conversions:

```
char c = '1';
int i = c;  // char to int

// char to int, and vice versa
switch (c) {
    case 1:
}
switch (i) {
    case '1':
}
```

Given the conversions required above, why does the char type not feature on Java's widening path?  Thanks.

Comment: Part of the reason is that `char` is unsigned and thus narrower in a sense than `short`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char` to `int` is of course a widening conversion. But `int` to `char` is not, as you seem to be thinking based on second `switch` statement. In that, it's actually the `'1'` char type in `case` which undergoes conversion to an `int` type based on it's unicode code point. Also, [JLS §5.1.2 - Widening Primitive conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) clearly state there is widening conversion from `char` to `int`.

Comment: Thanks.  I must have copied-and-pasted the "byte -> short -> int -> long -> float -> double" line from somewhere, thinking that was the correct rule for widening.

Comment: @user2911290 Actually while copy-pasting, you missed there must be a conversion frrom `char` -> `int` parallel to `byte` -> `short` -> `int`.